# How to create toggle class event in reactjs without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

In jQuery, we can easily set toggle event like,

```
$('div').click(function(){
   $('div').toggleClass('active');
});
```

But how to implement this kind of thing in reactjs with jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

To get toogling you to have to controll your state.

In this case i toggling the *style* attribute and you also can do it with your *className* attribute:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
          isVisible: true
        }
    },
    handleClick: function(){
        var notVisible = !this.state.isVisible;
        this.setState({
          isVisible: notVisible
        })
    },
    render: function() {
        var styleClass = this.state.isVisible? 'hidden':'visible';
        console.log(styleClass);
        return <div>
            <span style={{visibility: styleClass}}> Hello World</span>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
        </div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/21587/)

I hope i will help you.

Thanks

Comment: This code doesn't toggle class but easier to understand

Answer (score 3):

Inside your react component class you could have the toggle flag as part of state data `this.state.toggle`. `render` method will see use this data to add class or not. We can bind a click listener to the button to to flip the flag in state.

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        toggle: false
    };
},

clickHandler: function () {
    this.setState({ toggle: !this.state.toggle })
},

render: function () {
    var clsName = this.state.toggle ? 'active' : '';
    return <button className={ clsName } onClick={ this.clickHandler }>{ this.props.label }</button>;
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the state for doing something like this in several ways:

first of all you need to declare the state variable in your componenet:

```
getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            isActive: false
        };
}
```

then you will need an onClick function

```
handleClick: function(){
   this.setState({isActive: !this.state.isActive});
}
```

Now you need to use this property in you render method

Option 1: concatenating class using a "short if" form

```
<div
   className={this.state.isActive? "active" : ""}
   onClick={this.handleClick}
>
    Some content...
</div>
```

Option 2: by using the React classet addons that you can find at https://github.com/petehunt/react-classset

```
<div
   className={
        React.addons.classSet({
            active: this.state.isActive
        })
   }
   onClick={this.handleClick}
>
    Some content...
</div>
```

Edit: I have just found out that the option2 si deprecated and they suggest instead to use this utility:

https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

```
render () {
    var btnClass = classNames({
       'btn-pressed': this.state.isPressed,
    });
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
}
```

This code toggle **btn-pressed** class according buttons pressed state.

Comment: Yeah, you first need to create a state using `getInitialState` method. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In functional component, we can use **state** & **setState** of **useState**  hooks. The **active** className rendering depends on **active** state. And the toggle can be done by negating the previous active state.

```
const CarBrand = ({ brand }) => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div
            onClick={() => setActive(prevState => !prevState)}
            className={`car-brand ${active ? "active" : ""}`}
        >
            {brand}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const carBrands = [
    "Audi",
    "BMW",
    "Citroen",
    "Ford",
    "Honda",
    "Jaguar",
    "Land Rover",
    "Mercedes",
    "Mini",
    "Nissan",
    "Toyota",
    "Volvo",
];

const CarBrand = ({ brand }) => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div
            onClick={() => setActive(prevState => !prevState)}
            className={`car-brand ${active ? "active" : ""}`}
        >
            {brand}
        </div>
    )
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Car Brands</h1>
            <div className="car-brands">
                {carBrands.map((brand, i) => {
                    return <CarBrand key={i} brand={brand} />;
                })}
            </div>
        </div>         
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```css
.car-brands {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    width: 200px;
}

.car-brand {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.car-brand.active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div class='react'></div>
```